# How do I get a railroad diagram (syntax diagram) in Docbook starting from an EBNF source file?

Tags: docbook, ebnf

[Docbook 5 apparently supports EBNF.](http://www.docbook.org/schemas/ebnf) But it doesn't output a railroad diagram. Is it possible to make it output a railroad diagram (AKA [syntax diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_diagram))?

Comment: Looks like the docbook support for EBNF is some XML format, not the normal BNF syntax you'd expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DocBook schema includes XML elements for representing EBNF production rules, and HTML/FO output can be generated using the [DocBook XSL](https://sourceforge.net/projects/docbook/) stylesheets. However, there is no direct support for producing railroad diagrams. There are tools for creating railroad diagrams from plaintext EBNF sources, but I am not aware of any programs that do the same based on DocBook EBNF markup.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the answer mail on this question.